# Avoiding parsing when loading a file

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Suppose that I have the following file (*input.txt*):

```
1   2   sometext1
2   3   sometext2
3   4   sometext3
4   5   sometext4
```

i.e. a tab-delimited file where each line is made of two strings representing an `Integer` and a third string representing arbitrary text.

This file is the input for a `PigLatin` script:

```
input = load 'input.txt' as (a:int, b:int, c:chararray);
```

My assumption is that Pig is going to waste time parsing the text file to produce the corresponding integers. Am I correct?

I would like to store in a binary file the binary representation of the three integers.

How can I make Pig understanding such binary file? Should I simply extend the `LoadFunc` or do I need to use the `BinStorage`?

Comment: You may want to be careful about storing integers in raw binary, as then you have to take into account things such as big-endian vs. little-endian. Ignore this comment if all of the systems which will use this function are on the same architecture.

Answer (score 0):

How much time are you afraid to waste here? Assuming the rest of your script does anything meaningful or that your files are large enough (so that IO would be serious) the parsing effort will be negligible compared with everything else